# "This file has been modified outside of the source editor" when I save a file from inside VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Every time I save a file in VS2008, it immediately pops up the "This file has been modified outside of the source editor. Do you want to reload it?" message box.

[image]

But I'm editing and saving it **from inside** of VS2008! This happens on a particular header file in the project, other files in the same project are fine.

Has anyone else ever encountered this weird behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what it was, and I feel really dumb now.

I have a junction point (an NTFS symlink for dirs) from C:\Projects to C:\Workspace, because the project has hardcoded paths (I use C:\Workspace and the guy who developed it uses C:\Projects).

The file was opened in 2 tabs, as `C:\Workspace\Project1\file1.h` and as `C:\Projects\Project1\file1.h`. Same file, but VS doesn't know that, it thinks it's 2 different files!

So when I save it from one tab, VS thinks that the "other" file is edited externally.

OK, I doubt anyone else would ever have this problem, as almost nobody uses symlinks in Windows even though NTFS supports it.